# could not load abc.apk

Tags: android

I'm a totally newbie to the Android SDK. I have been installed
Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede), Android 2.1 SDK with JRE 6 updated 7.

I need to use external .jar 's, when i load that jar in
eclispe,automatically abc.apk is missing and showing the error like

[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)
[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)
[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)
[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)
[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)
[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)

[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)

[2010-09-20 08:33:54 - CodeFinder]warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class was probably
produced by a broken compiler.)

[2010-09-20 08:33:55 - CodeFinder]1 error; aborting

[2010-09-20 08:33:55 - CodeFinder]Conversion to Dalvik format failed
with error 1

if i remove my .jar from build path then automatically abc.apk is
build.so plz help me
how to use external jar in order to run android apps.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer for your statement `when i load that jar in eclispe`

right click Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Select libraries tab --> Add External Jar.

you must set the external .jar's in the right way. else it shows an error. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....hope you havent read the complete problem of mine...plz check the last line of the error,when i update the build path i am getting the error.